# Double-Array Trie Question

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to understand Double-Array Trie implementation from http://linux.thai.net/~thep/datrie/datrie.html
But I do not understand following part.

```
check[base[s] + c] = s
base[s] + c = t
```

What does adding `c` means here.

Can anybody explain algorithm in simple language.

Comment: Do you understand how the Triple-Array implementation works?  The Double-Array version only blends the `base` and `next` arrays into one.  The role of adding `c` is the same as in the Triple-Array version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you collaps a 2D array into a 1D array:

```
int arr2D[2][3];
int arr1D[2 * 3]; // # of rows * # of columns

// access element [1][2] of 2D array, i.e., the last element
int elem2D = arr2D[1][2];
// access element [1][2] of 1D array, i.e., the last element
int elem1D = arr1D[1 * 3 + 2];
// =========================================================
lets visualize the array access:
arr2D => x/y 0  1  2
          0 [N][N][N]
+1 on x > 1 [N][N][N]
+2 on y ---------- ^
y_len  =>   ^-------^ 3 elements
so the access happens with x * y_len + y
                           1 *   3   + 2
now for the 1D array
we want the second row, so we go with 1 * 3
(0-based access, y_len = 3)
and then we want the 3rd element, so + 2
(again, 0-based access)
arr1D =>  x  0  1  2 
            [N][N][N]
             3  4  5
1 * 3 = 3 > [N][N][N]
      + 2 = 5 ---- ^
```

I hope I didn't make this too complicated (even though I think I did...). :)

Answer (score 0):

Characters are "zero based", i.e., 'a' is 0, 'b' is 1, 'c' is 2, et cetera.  Looking up "a" would mean to add that 0 to the base address of the current node and check the owner at that index.  If that owner is the current node, there is a string starting with "a" from the current node in the trie, and the base address at that index is the base address for the next lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your code to the following:

```
check[base[s] + c] = s
next[base[s] + c] = t
```

In the scenario that state `s` accepts a character `c` and transformed into state `t`: `s - c -> t`.
The key point is what `base[s]` means.
As a state may accept multiple characters:

|  |c1|c2|c3|
|--|--|--|--|
| s| x| y| z|
The problem is how you express these mappings of `s-c1->x`, `s-c2->y`, `s-c3->z`. Traditionally, a `map` is a good practice:

```
class State {
    Map<Character, State> mappings;
}
```

But what if you use an array to express the mappings?
`base[s]` is a base index in `next` array, from which an offset `c` is added.
`base[s] + c` is the final index in `next` to store the next state mapped from state `s` and character `c`. Note that character `c` is actually an integer in programming language.